# PHP and Mysql trying to run code on DB

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Good Day

I am new to html, php I am trying to set up a page to run a sql query to move data from one table into another one. The trouble I am having is that I require a user to input a date that needs to pass to the query.

I have checked on the net and viewed the question that this is marked as a duplicate of. And am still unable to get this working.

My Html is as follows for the submit part.

```
<div class = "boxed">
<p> First Date to be used for comparasion</p>

<form method="post">

Date1: <input type="text" name="date1"/>
       <input type="Submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

My Php is

```
<?php   
session_start();

include_once 'include/dbconf.php';

if(isset($_POST['date1']))

$d1 =  mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['date1']);

$sql1 = "insert ignore into compare2 SELECT * FROM Compare where Date = 
'$d1'";
$sqldata = mysqli_query($sql1,$conn) or die ('error updaing Table');

echo "Table updated";

mysql_close($con)

?>
```

My include/dbconfig.php works as I use it on another page and connect succesfully to the DB.

It looks like my query doesn't get the user defined input passed to it. 
I don't get any errors either in the httpd error.log.

You advise and help would be most appreciated.

Updated PHP

```
 <?php  

session_start();

include_once 'include/dbconf.php';

if(isset($_POST['date1']))
{   

$d1 =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date1']);

$sql1 = "insert ignore into compare2 SELECT * FROM Compare where Date = 
'$d1'";
$sqldata = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1) or die ('error updaing Table');

echo "Table updated";
}

mysqli_close($conn)

?>
```

Still not running the sql to update the table.

Comment: [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) requires 2 params.

Comment: I would suggest to you to try out PDO and prepared statements. PDO is better than MySQLi and prepared statements are better than queries with escaped strings.

Comment: And hopefully `mysql_close($con)` is a typo. :/

Comment: Use `prepared statements` along with `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. don't relie on escaping. they will not prevent SQL INJECTION. also `mysqli_real_escape_string` need two paramteres frst is db connection object, which is missed in your case.

Comment: @AllanvanStaden Separate your debugging from php for a moment. 
 Does a manually built query run successfully in your phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @mickmackusa yes it does.

Comment: Then we will need to see some more error checking implemented.   Let's see you confirm there is a successful connection and no syntax errors in the query.  Like AliveToDie, I'd rather you implement prepared statements with placeholders.  If it rums in your phpMyAdmin, then your date format must be right.  Are you validating the date?  Escape doesn't validate.

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to:

```
session_start();

include_once 'include/dbconf.php';

if(isset($_POST['date1'])) {
    $d1 =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date1']);

    $sql1 = "insert ignore into compare2 SELECT * FROM Compare where Date = '$d1'";
    $sqldata = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1) or die ('error updaing Table');

    echo "Table updated";
}

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer, what did you do and why is it working?

Comment: LenaCapo updated to your answer and unfortunalty didn't work